# ActiveRecord find by number of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I'd like an ActiveRecord query that lets me return all the **users** that have zero **email_sessions**. Here're my models:

```
class User
    has_many :email_sessions
end

class EmailSession
    belongs_to :user
end
```

It would be pretty straight-forward to do this after the AR query, like so:

```
User.all.reject {|u| u.email_sessions.count > 0}
```

But it gets to be pretty computationally-expensive as it steps through every user to check the count. I also want to use **arel** to chain together different **where** statements after this.

Any ActiveRecord sooper geniuses want to take a crack at this? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[64] pry(main)> User.all.reject {|u| u.trial_end_date == nil or u.email_sessions.count > 0}.count
=> 138
[65] pry(main)> User.where("users.id NOT IN(?) AND users.trial_end_date IS NOT NULL", EmailSession.group(:user_id).select(:user_id).map { |es| es.user_id }).count
=> 138
```

Comment: Victor is cheating a bit because I work with him, and he tested on the actual data. This solution works perfectly.

Comment: The question is why did you have to post on SO when Victor is there? :)

Comment: Also, doesn't even match the question.

At the very least edit the question to match this, so someone in the future can make sense of it.

Comment: While good information, this would be really confusing to future readers. Please change to be a general answer fitting the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, but unfortunately in an older version of Rails. Perhaps there are better ways of doing it in newer versions.

```
User.find(:all,
  :include => :email_sessions,
  :conditions => 'email_sessions.id IS NULL'
)
```

EDIT: Using ARel:

```
User.includes(:email_sessions).where('email_sessions.id IS NULL')
```